# Mount by UUID or LABEL

Tags: linux, debian, mount, label, uuid

In Linux it is possible to mount a device (disk) by UUID or label. I have used UUID for a while mainly because I was picked up a discussion on IRC that mounting by label was a really horrible idea.

I fail to see why mounting by label would be a bad idea if one would choose a pretty unique label name like 6581_var, 6502_root, 8580_home, DFF180_usr, 68030_boot, BFEC01_WD_Disk05. etc.... ;)

So my questions are:

1. Why is it a good idea to always mount with UUID?
2. Why is it a bad idea to always mount with UUID?
3. Why is it a good idea to always mount with LABEL?
4. Why is it a bad idea to always mount with LABEL?
5. Is there a benefit to choose one over the other for systems using systemd ?!
6. What is more likely to get corrupted. A LABEL or UUID
7. If a disk for example gets a firmware upgrade can that change the UUID?!

Comment: 1) and 3) good because it doesn't matter if you create/delete partitions or change SATA/ATA disk channel- partition numbers will be changed and your system still will work properly. 6) both have the same chances to get corrupted. 7) I don't thinks so- UUID has been generated during partition creation and has nothing to do with hardware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answers

- **Q1-4**: It's not. Right tool should be used for specific purpose. See below.
- **Q5**: System using systemd are developed enough to show no difference.
- **Q6**: In common case - neither. They are both stored in the same place (formatting header or so) and changed by the same mechanism.
- **Q7**: No. Partition UUID can be only changed directly (see below) or by reformatting (i.e. creating new formatting) the partition.

### Actually

Assuming we are talking about partition formatting (e.g. file system) *UUID* and *Label*.

There are also partition UUID and Label - commonly referred as *partUUID* and *partlabel* - if disk partitioning scheme supports them: e.g. GPT, but not MBR. They are also could be used to identify partition and, in some cases (see below), could an only way to do it.

Both *UUID* and *Label* are managed using tools specific to partition formatting used:

- ext2/3/4: `tune2fs`
- FAT: `mlabel`
- swap: `swaplabel`
- LUKS: `cryptsetup luksUUID`
- ...

Please note, both *UUID* and *Label* exist only if partition formatting exists (and supported by your kernel) and the formatting supports *UUID* and/or *Label* attributes. For example partition encrypted using dm-crypt without LUKS extension does not have *UUID* and *Label* as it does not use any header (but file system inside encrypted container could have them both). FAT-family file systems don't support *UUID* (they have serial number instead), but do support *Label*.

The main differences between using Label and UUID are:

- *UUID* is for lower level

  - created automatically (always exists)
  - managed automatically
  - guaranteed to be unique (in the most cases)
  - not human friendly
- *Label* is for higher level

  - should be created explicitly
  - managed manually
  - human friendly (easy to remember and type)

So if you not going to manage labels for partition(s) the choice is obvious - UUID. If you need more flexibility and/or readability for you system configuration - you could use labels.

For example, for cloned or [automanaged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) systems using labels could be more suitable: after system cloned UUID's could change. If not for ext2/3/4 (depends on cloning method), it definitely change for LUKS-encrypted partitions (we need do `luksFormat` at least to create new encryption key). So using *Label* in this case could be convenient.

Also Udev rule mounts removable media to `/media/<user>/<label>` if *Label* exits. If not - `/media/<user>/<UUID>` used instead.